# Bris mila/ sefira haomer

Tags: brit-milah, sefirat-ha-omer

Are there any connections between the mitzva of mila and sefiras Haomer (besides that the father of baby and sandak can have a haircut during the sefira)?

Comment: ברכות שראוי המברך לברכם מעומד. ברכת העומר ברכת ציצית ברכת לולב וברכת מילה וכולהו נפקא להו מגזרה שוה מספירת העומר כדכתיב מהחל חרמש בקמה ודרשו בקומה. ודרשינן לכם כתיב בעומר וספרתם לכם. בציצית והיה לכם לציצית. בלולב ולקחתם לכם. במילה המול לכם ואאבי הבן קאי שצריך לברך בעמידה וכן רגילין. Kol Bo 22:15